# Second AJAX call unloading result of the first

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Code below is run in the onLoad event of the page.  I  first would like to populate a drop down menu with getCompany() and then fill in data from the server into text boxes and choose the selected option.

Both functions work, in fact when I reload the page with debugger running and step into everything both do what they are supposed to.

When I just open the page or reload with out debugger the text boxes are filled but the options disappear from the dropdown, why is that?

```
<script>
        var result;
        function init(){
            var name = window.name;
            name = name.split(",");
            getCompany();
            setTimeout(200);
            if (name[0] = "update"){
                id = name[1];
                getTenant(id);
                //get the info for the line that called the edit function
                //fill fields with information from server
            }
        }

        function getCompany() { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function x() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("company").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getCompany.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

        function getTenant(id){
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function y() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    result = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    result = result.split(",");
                    //fill the form with old information
                    document.getElementById("fname").value = result[0];
                    document.getElementById("lname").value = result[1];
                    document.getElementById("company").selectedIndex = result[2];
                    document.getElementById("phone").value = result[3];
                    document.getElementById("email").value = result[4];
                    document.getElementById("crm").value = result[5];
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getTenant.php?p=" + id,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: But it might be on-topic for Code Reviews.

Comment: @RossPatterson Not quite. CR requires the code to work as expected, and then offers feedback on how to improve it (think: architecture, best practices, correctness, …). CR is not about solving problems. But in this case, the code is *not* working as expected and OP is trying to solve a problem. Therefore, it's unsuitable for CR. Please read [their help/on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: Could you try copying the results of the first call into a local variable?

There may be something to the variable being changed that could be an issue as it could appear that the "xmlhttp" variable is global in scope which may cause the issue. The other thought is to up the timeout between calls as that could also be something different when debugging.

Comment: if (name[0] = "update") : Shouldn't this be, if (name[0] == "update") ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume the input fields you are filling in data in the second request belong to the data fetched from the first request. I also assume you are using the `setTimeout()` to delay the 2nd request...

Javascripts are single threaded. To provide asynchronous behavior js uses callback mechanism. After sending a request to the server, js doesn't wait until the response comes. JS keeps executing the rest of code until the results from the server comes. When the response comes from the server the code in the callback function  `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` is executed. Because of that, both requests may happen at almost the same time and consequently the response for the 2nd request may come before the first response which leads the behavior you see as an error.

When you debug, you execute line by line. Therefore there is enough time to get the response for the first request before getting the response for the second request.

As a solution you can move the code for the second request inside the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` callback in the code for the first request. Then as the callback is always executed after the results are fetched, the second request is sent after the response for the first one comes.

You may google about **asynchronous javascript** and learn in details...

```
<script>
    var result;
    function init(){
        var name = window.name;
        name = name.split(",");
        getCompany(name);
    }

    function getCompany(name) { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function x() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("company").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                if (name[0] == "update"){
                   id = name[1];
                   getTenant(id);
                   //get the info for the line that called the edit function
                   //fill fields with information from server
                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getCompany.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function getTenant(id){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function y() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                result = xmlhttp.responseText;
                result = result.split(",");
                //fill the form with old information
                document.getElementById("fname").value = result[0];
                document.getElementById("lname").value = result[1];
                document.getElementById("company").selectedIndex = result[2];
                document.getElementById("phone").value = result[3];
                document.getElementById("email").value = result[4];
                document.getElementById("crm").value = result[5];
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getTenant.php?p=" + id,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of a race condition between the two XHR calls made from getCompany and getTenant methods. Even though you are making the getTenant call 200ms after making the first XHR call there is no guarantee that the getComapny XHR call will finish first. When that happens the follwoing line of code

```
document.getElementById("company").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

removes all the options from the menu and also resets the selected index. To circumvent this issue do not make getTenant(id); call from init method. Instead make it from the success handler of the getCompany XHR call.

```
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function x() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("company").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    **getTenant(id);**
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make two different object name instead of one (xmlhttp). Like

- in 'getCompany()' function object name is 'xmlhttp'
- in 'getTenant()' function changed object name to  'xmlTalenthttp' (or any other name which you wish)